# Failed to setup gcp repository using elasticsearch operator

Tags: java, elasticsearch, kubernetes

I'm launching 3 elastic nodes using elastic operator and i tried to set up automated snapshots for these instances.

I followed this [doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-on-k8s/current/k8s-snapshots.html)

I minified the json of the service account key and created a file called gcs.client.default.credentials_file with no file extension and added this file to kubernetes secrets.

And added the secureSettings.secretName field to the spec of the elastic cluster and added the secret name to it which was gcs-credentials

But i get this error on the logs

```
{"@timestamp":"2022-12-26T18:45:40.037Z", "log.level":"ERROR", "message":"fatal exception while booting Elasticsearch", "ecs.version": "1.2.0","service.name":"ES_ECS","event.dataset":"elasticsearch.server","process.thread.name":"main","log.logger":"org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch","elasticsearch.node.name":"elasticsearch-cluster-es-node-1","elasticsearch.cluster.name":"elasticsearch-cluster","error.type":"java.lang.IllegalStateException","error.message":"failed to load plugin class [org.elasticsearch.repositories.gcs.GoogleCloudStoragePlugin]","error.stack_trace":"java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to load plugin class [org.elasticsearch.repositories.gcs.GoogleCloudStoragePlugin]\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.5.0/org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadPlugin(PluginsService.java:607)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.5.0/org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadBundle(PluginsService.java:482)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.5.0/org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadBundles(PluginsService.java:290)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.5.0/org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.<init>(PluginsService.java:159)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.5.0/org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.lambda$getPluginsServiceCtor$14(PluginsService.java:634)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.5.0/org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:406)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.5.0/org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:316)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.5.0/org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch$2.<init>(Elasticsearch.java:214)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.5.0/org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.initPhase3(Elasticsearch.java:214)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.5.0/org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:67)\nCaused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:79)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:484)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.5.0/org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.loadPlugin(PluginsService.java:600)\n\t... 9 more\nCaused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: failed to load GCS client credentials from [gcs.client.default.credentials_file]\n\tat org.elasticsearch.repositories.gcs.GoogleCloudStorageClientSettings.loadCredential(GoogleCloudStorageClientSettings.java:265)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.repositories.gcs.GoogleCloudStorageClientSettings.getClientSettings(GoogleCloudStorageClientSettings.java:221)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.repositories.gcs.GoogleCloudStorageClientSettings.load(GoogleCloudStorageClientSettings.java:209)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.repositories.gcs.GoogleCloudStoragePlugin.reload(GoogleCloudStoragePlugin.java:88)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.repositories.gcs.GoogleCloudStoragePlugin.<init>(GoogleCloudStoragePlugin.java:36)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:67)\n\t... 12 more\nCaused by: java.io.IOException: Invalid PKCS#8 data.\n\tat com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials.privateKeyFromPkcs8(ServiceAccountCredentials.java:496)\n\tat com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials.fromPkcs8(ServiceAccountCredentials.java:474)\n\tat com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials.fromJson(ServiceAccountCredentials.java:212)\n\tat com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(ServiceAccountCredentials.java:548)\n\tat com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(ServiceAccountCredentials.java:520)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.repositories.gcs.GoogleCloudStorageClientSettings.lambda$loadCredential$13(GoogleCloudStorageClientSettings.java:257)\n\tat java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:569)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.repositories.gcs.SocketAccess.doPrivilegedIOException(SocketAccess.java:33)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.repositories.gcs.GoogleCloudStorageClientSettings.loadCredential(GoogleCloudStorageClientSettings.java:256)\n\t... 17 more\n"}
ERROR: Elasticsearch did not exit normally - check the logs at /usr/share/elasticsearch/logs/elasticsearch-cluster.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following lines to your configuration (on each Elasticsearch):

```
elasticsearch01:
     image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.6.2
...
     ulimits:
       memlock:
         soft: -1
         hard: -1
```

Also check this link on [Elasticsearch](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/error-with-elasticsearch-after-prod-config/230766/2) for more detailed information.